# WCF synchronization between WPF client and server best practices

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, .net-4.0, synchronization

I am new in sync-ing data between the server and the client, so I want to ask for your advise on how would be better to achieve it. (Best Practices).

I created WPF app, which will be getting data (via WCF) from Web Server and stored them in local database. In future I will sending new or edited data to server.

When I start up my app, I need get new data that I don't have, but it's on the server. 
But getting all data every time is redundant, so I need to get only new data. 
Also some data maybe changed on server, so I need to get these data as well. And so on.

*Questions*:
Could you please give me a guidance on how should I do that or any useful resource I can read and learn about it? Do I need to use some particular framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [SyncFramework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb736753).
Also, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726004.aspx) section will be useful.